# How do you express a one event followed by another query in StreamInsight?

Tags: streaminsight

Scouring the StreamInsight documentation, it seems that it should be possible to express a query of the form '***for a given event stream, generate output when event A is followed by event B***', but I can't see how to express this as a LINQ query, nor can I find any examples in the doc.

Can anyone help?  Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This might help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/romans/archive/2010/11/30/joint-forces.aspx

Comment: Thanks @romans - that article gives a reasonable idea of the approach, cheers.